# Drone CI-Unable to start a new build: json: cannotunmarshal array into Go value of typegitee.content

Tags: github, cicd, drone.io

I created a drone docker container and made drone associated with gitee (China's github), but I get this error when I create a new build on the drone page
Unable to start a new build: json: cannotunmarshal array into Go value of typegitee.content
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vygd7.png)

How to solve this problem